# Как мне настроить .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при переходе, например, по ссылке http://localhost/about/somepage открывалась страница, которая также открывается по адресу http://localhost/index.php?section=about&id=somepage. Т.е. мне нужно подстроить под себя Rewrite. Как это сделать? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.*)$ index.php?section=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

но гораздо правильнее делать так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|js|swf|zip|tgz|txt|log)$ index.php?path=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|.html)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

в данном случае все запросы перенаправляются в скрипт, который уже сам решает что показывать клиенту.